# Deriving force between continuous distributions of two volume charges without using infinitesimals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, physics, multiple-integral, electromagnetism

We know that force between two point charges is:

$$\vec{F}=k\ q\ q'\ \dfrac{\hat{r}}{r^2}\tag1$$

From here how shall we derive the equation for force between *continuous distributions* of two volume charges, i.e.

$$\vec{F}=k\ \int_{q} \int_{q'} \dfrac{\hat{r}}{r^2}\ dq'\ dq \tag2$$

Unlike physicists and physics teachers, I want to **derive it in a rigorous way by not using infinitesimals**. I know it is pretty simple using the infinitesimal argument. We replace the two point charges $q'$ and $q$ with infinitesimal charges $\ dq'$ and $\ dq$ respectively. Then add up the infinitesimal bits over the volume to obtain $(2)$.

**Please give the in between steps to reach equation $(2)$ from equation $(1)$.**

> **Edit:**
> I know the cube is becoming more and more like a point. Still I don't get it. Can someone at least show why $$\lim_{a \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta^2 F}{k\ \Delta q\ \Delta q'\dfrac{1}{r^2}}=1$$ is true (where $a$ is the side of each cube with which we have partitioned both volume charges.).

Comment: If you want to obtain formula (2) from (1), I believe there are no other way than using splitting continuos volume into infinitesimal parts and using the fact that electrostatic force is additive. But in my opinion it is better to write $\rho' dV'$ instead of $dq'$ and $\rho dV$ instead of $dq$.

Comment: But I want to do in a standard rigorous way

Comment: I believe splitting into infinitesimal parts is rigorous, but to be more rigorous you can do so: You can split any continuos charge into smaller charges with specific charges, positions, shapes and orientations. Then $\vec{F}$ is sum of acting forces between parts of $q$ and parts of $q'$. Then you can make splitting in such a way that maximum part size is approaching to zero. In such case small parts acting forces are approaching to expression (1), so the limit of $\vec{F}$ as the size of maximum part is approaching zero is expression (2).

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: "make splitting in such a way that maximum part size is approaching to zero. In such case small parts acting forces are approaching to expression (1)". Can you show rigorously why this is true?

Comment: Small parts are approaching to points therefore small acting forces are approaching to expression for point charges.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu : In other words can you show using equation (1) why $$\lim_{a \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta^2 F}{k\ \Delta q\ \Delta q'\dfrac{1}{r^2}}=1$$ where $a$ is the side of each cube with which we have partitioned both volume charges.

Comment: This fact is following from word "point" in description of expression (1) and cannot be showed formally.

Comment: I know the cube is becoming more and more like a point. Still I don't get it. Can you at least show why $$\lim_{a \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta^2 F}{k\ \Delta q\ \Delta q'\dfrac{1}{r^2}}=1$$ is true.

Comment: There is no $a$ in your equation, so the limit argument is the same as the limit

Comment: $\Delta q=\rho a ^3$ and $\Delta q'=\rho' a ^3$ Also the numerator $F$ is going towards zero as $a$ goes to zero.